# ionic page creation error "unhandled exception"

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I am trying to make new page in my ionic project and I always face this error, I tried to uninstall/install ionic and angular but it is the same
[image]

```html
Hadi@Hadis-MacBook-Pro appcopy3 % ionic generate page pages/famade   
> ng generate page pages/famade --project=app
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility/project'
Require stack:
- /Users/Hadi/Desktop/Projects/appcopy3/node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/schematics/page/index.js
- /Users/Hadi/Desktop/Projects/appcopy3/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js
- /Users/Hadi/Desktop/Projects/appcopy3/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
- /Users/Hadi/Desktop/Projects/appcopy3/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/json-schema.js
- /Users/Hadi/Desktop/Projects/appcopy3/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
- /Users/Hadi/Desktop/Projects/appcopy3/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
- /Users/Hadi/Desktop/Projects/appcopy3/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
- /Users/Hadi/Desktop/Projects/appcopy3/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
See "/private/var/folders/nf/xlscyy5j3d3d83y3bl7p38640000gn/T/ng-LRzw1R/angular-errors.log" for further details.
[ERROR] Could not generate page.
```

Comment: Use npm uninstall -g @angular/cli , then npm install -g @angular/cli, then npm uninstall -g @ionic/cli, then npm install -g @ionic/cli and that should fix the whole error since tour problem is between ionic and angular versions

Comment: Also ensure you have @ionic/angular installed.